# What will be the right location to place time out warning code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, timeout-dialog.js

I am using Timeout-Dialog.js (https://github.com/rigoneri/timeout-dialog.js?next=%2Ftimeout-dialog.js%2F&timeout=t) and it is working fine as expected. I place the javascript at _Layout.cshtml. Somehow when the session is about to expire the TimeOut warning dialog is also  prompted even though current view is the log on screen. May I know what will be the best location to apply the time out code ?

The code that has been placed in _Layout.cshtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var timeout = 1800000; //30 minutes idle
        $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function () {
            // function you want to fire when the user goes idle
            $.timeoutDialog({ timeout: 1, countdown: 60, logout_redirect_url: 'http://localhost:57850/EMAP/Account/Login', restart_on_yes: false });

        });
        $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function () {            
            // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
        });
        $.idleTimer(timeout);
    });

</script>
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a separate layout for your login view, or check the action name before running the code:

```
$(function () {
    if("@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")" != "MyActionName") {
        var timeout = 1800000; //30 minutes idle
        $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function () {
            // function you want to fire when the user goes idle
            $.timeoutDialog({ timeout: 1, countdown: 60, logout_redirect_url: 'http://localhost:57850/EMAP/Account/Login', restart_on_yes: false });

        });
        $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function () {            
            // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
        });
        $.idleTimer(timeout);
    }
});
```